# Scrollbar issue in WPF ListBox

Tags: wpf, listbox, infragistics, listboxitem, xamdatagrid

We are working on field chooser and used custom code to get the search functionality in field chooser of xamDataGrid.
We used a Text box to search and a List box to keep the fields of field chooser.
The Code that we have used:

```
    <StackPanel>
    <TextBox TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
        <ListBox x:Name="PART_FieldsListBox" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding CurrentFields}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedField, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                 <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                                     <Setter Property="Template">
                                     <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                         <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                             </Border>
                                             </ControlTemplate>
                                     </Setter.Value>
                                     </Setter>
                             </Style>
                      </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Space" Command="{x:Static igDP:FieldChooserCommands.ToggleVisibility}"/>
            </ListBox.InputBindings>
            </ListBox>
```

I know the problem is Stack panel. But due to text search code, we cannot remove stack panel.
Code for search we used:

```
    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
            ListBox lb = (((sender as TextBox).Parent as StackPanel).Children[1] as ListBox);
            foreach (var item in lb.ItemsSource as ReadOnlyObservableCollection<FieldChooserEntry>)
            {
                ListBoxItem listBoxItem = (lb.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListBoxItem);
                if ((sender as TextBox).Text.ToString() != "")
                {
                    if (item.Field.Label.ToString().ToLower().Contains((sender as TextBox).Text.ToLower()))
                        listBoxItem.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    else
                        listBoxItem.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                else
                    listBoxItem.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }

    }
```

We have also replaced Grid in place of Stack panel. But after adding grid, Text change event thrown "Object reference error"

The reason for the issue we have described is contained within the TextChanged event of the search TextBox we are using.
A null reference exception is thrown because not all the items inside the ListBox are currently visualized, and this way the ContainerFromItem method is not able to find them all as visual elements. Since we have replaced the StackPanel with a Grid.

Comment: If you have replaced the StackPanel with a Grid. Have you changed ```.Parent as StackPanel``` to ```.Parent as Grid``` ?

Comment: Yes, I have changed .Parent as Grid.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no code available for your FieldChooserEntry and other elements, I'd suggest the following:

Instead of using `lb.ItemSource` in the `foreach`, can you use `ListBox.Items` and then you would only need to cast the item as `FieldChooserEntry` in the `if`?

This way you can avoid the complexity of the `ItemContainerGenerator` which may not be best way to get the items. It may cause problems with virtualization.

As for the error with the Grid, you might want to check if `Children[1]` is in fact the ListBox. The order of controls in Grid and StackPanel may be different.

If you need more detail or if this still does not fix the problem, you may need to post the code for your FieldChooserEntry object - at least the structure.

Comment: I am not getting List box item after casting by following code.         

ListBox lb = (((sender as TextBox).Parent as Grid).Children[1] as ListBox);
                foreach (var item in lb.Items)
                {
                    ListBoxItem listBoxItem = item as ListBoxItem;
                }

Comment: I'd suggest setting a breakpoint on the ```ListBox lb =  ...``` line, and see the list of Children to see which one is ListBox.

Comment: lb.Items are coming FieldChooserEntry. And while we are casting it to ListBox Item, ListBoxItem is null.
Because we cannot cast FieldChooserEntry to ListBoxItem directly.

Comment: Then you can cast it to FieldChooserEntry instead.